# google drive files.list doesn't show file/folder created by non app

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

I have problem listing file from google drive via google drive api (using python).
I shows only the files created via the api. The other files in the folder created by human via google drive interface are not shown.

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


files = DRIVE.files().list().execute()

for item in files.get('items', []):
    print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (item.get('title'), item.get('id')))
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your code?  Is it possible that you are only requesting items of a certain type?

Comment: Hi here are my code

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


files = DRIVE.files().list().execute()

for item in files.get('items', []):
 print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (item.get('title'), item.get('id')))

Comment: Please use the Edit Question link to add the code to your question.

Comment: sorry about it. I've edited

Comment: Is it possible that you're only seeing the first page of results?  "The list of files. If nextPageToken is populated, then this list may be incomplete and an additional page of results should be fetched." from [Drive API Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

Comment: someone comment here and It's been disappeared. he suggests me to use scope:

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

it worked!!